# How can this PHP logic control structure be refactored?

Tags: php, if-statement, refactoring, control-structure

My gut tells me that there is a better, perhaps one-line refactor for the following code:

```
if (isset($x))
{
    if (isset($y))
    {
        $z = array_merge($x,$y);
    }
    else
    {
        $z = $x;
    }
}
else
{
    $z = $y;
}
```

If I wasn't worried about warning errors, a simple `array_merge($x,$y)` would work, but I'd like to know a better way to do this. Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$z = array_merge(
    isset($x) ? $x : array(),
    isset($y) ? $y : array()
);
```

This will return an empty array if `$x` and `$y` are not set.  If only one is set, it will return that array.  If both are set, it will return the result of `array_merge()` run on the arrays.

That is not quite the behavior of your code above, but I believe it is the behavior you intended.  (I believe, in your code, that `$z` will not be an array if both `$x` and `$y` are not set.)

By the way, this code assumes that if `$x` and `$y` are set, that they are arrays.  If that is not the case, you should either run `is_array()` on them to confirm they are arrays or use [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) to make sure they are arrays when `array_merge()` runs.

Comment: Excellent answer, and returning a blank array helps me avoid checking is_array() later on. Thank you!